# Loading files for theme and child theme (Require)

Tags: theme-development, child-theme, directory

There seems to be so many options which one should i go for..it's really confusing? I have used `get_template_directory()`. What i want is to use a function that works best with child theme and that should work alone if no child theme is used..pls help

- get_theme_file_uri()
- get_parent_theme_file_uri()
- get_theme_file_path()
- get_parent_theme_file_path()
- get_template_directory()
- TEMPLATEPATH

Comment: And what is the problem with `get_template_directory()`?

Comment: @kero ..as coding requirement mentions..It is recommended that the following WordPress 4.7+ functions be used, as they greatly improve the child theming capabilities of the theme:get_theme_file_uri()
get_parent_theme_file_uri()
get_theme_file_path()
get_parent_theme_file_path()

Comment: @kero i have no problem with get_template_directory()..i think it won't allow overriding...not sure if any of other functions as advantage over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_theme_file_uri()`, `get_theme_file_path()`, `get_parent_theme_file_uri()` and `get_parent_theme_file_path()` are relatively new (introduced in WordPress 4.7) functions that have a couple of significant advantages over using `get_template_directory()`.

- `get_theme_file()` and `get_theme_file_path ()` allow you to reference files in your theme in a way that allows them to be replaced by a child theme. This lets you do things like allow images to be replaced, which wasn't previously possible (without a custom function).
- They are all *filterable*, which allows child themes and plugins to replace them with files either outside a theme, or with files that aren't in the same directory as they were in a parent theme. The filter would also let you prevent the inclusion of a file entirely.

The functions that end in `_path()` return the *path* to the files, so would be used for including files for use on the server, while the functions ending in `_uri()` return the URL to the file, for use on the front-end.

The `_parent_theme_` functions let you reference files without letting them be replaced by a child theme.

Since the introduction of these functions the only reason you would use the `template_directory` or `stylesheet_directory` functions would be to just get the URL or path to the directory itself.

You shouldn't need to ever use the `TEMPLATEPATH` constant.

Comment: That really helps, thank you :)..i think template_directory or stylesheet_directory will be still required for version below 4.7

Comment: I can’t imagine why anybody writing code now would need to worry about that. That version is already 2 years old.